# C++ converting a string to integers in a lengthy string

Tags: c++

I am writing a program where I will be given a string such as:

5,6,10

and I've made a program that takes the numbers 5 6 10 (ignoring the commas) and puts them into a vector.
The only problem with my program is that if I do something like

5,6,f

it'll turn that f into a 0. Whereas I want the program to just report an error if it sees anything but a 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ,

How can I fix my program to do this? Here is my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string str, temp;

    cout << "enter string: \n";
    getline (cin, str);
    vector<int> vec;
    int num;

    for (int j=0; j < str.size(); j++)
{
    int num2= str.size()-1;

    if (isdigit(str[j]))
    {
        temp+= str[j];
        num = atoi(temp.c_str());
        if (num2 ==j)  //if program is at end of string and it's still a number
            vec.push_back(num); //push back value
    }
    else if (str[j] == ',')
    {
        num = atoi(temp.c_str());
        temp.clear();
        vec.push_back(num);

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "error\n";
        temp.clear();
    }

}
    for (int k=0; k < vec.size(); k++)
        cout << vec[k] <<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not safe to use `atoi`, use [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) instead.

From `atoi`'s documentation:

> If str does not point to a valid C-string, or if the converted value
>   would be out of the range of values representable by an int, it causes
>   undefined behavior.

Example:

```
// ...

char *end;
long int res = strtol(str, &end, 10);
if (str == eptr) {
    throw std::invalid_argument("invalid strtol argument");
}
if (errno == ERANGE) {
    throw std::out_of_range("strtol argument out of range");
}
```

**Update:** Your code should look something like this:

```
char *iter = str.c_str(); // your str
char *end;
while ( *iter ) {
    int res = strtol(iter, &end, 10);

    // not a number, skip it and continue with the next one
    if (iter == end) {
        iter++;
        cout << "error: " << *iter << endl;
        continue;
    }

    // handle the out-of-range error
    if (errno == ERANGE) {
        cout << "overflow: " << string(iter, end) << endl;
    } else {
        // number is valid
        vec.push_back(res);
    }

    // continue iterating, skip char at (*end) since it's not an integer
    iter = end + 1;
}
```

Warn: Previous code was not compiled nor tested

Comment: I'm having trouble implementing strtol with my program. I read through cpp's definition of it and it's still kinda iffy. Could you give me an example with my program or maybe a head start?